# No zeros or poles implies regular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

The following is Theorem 8.14 of Milne's [notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf) (page 176): Let $V$ be a normal variety, let $ f $ be a rational function on $V$. If $f$ has no zeros or poles on an open subset $U$ of $V$, then $f$ is regular on $U$. The proof says to apply a commutative algebra result: a noetherian domain $A$ is normal if and only if $A_p$ is a DVR for all prime ideals $p$ of height $1$ and $A = \bigcap_{\text{ht}(p) = 1} A_p$. I don't see how this implies the theorem or how it is related to the prior discussion of divisors and Picard group. I hope someone can help me clarify this exposition.

Comment: How would you define a normal variety? and $f$ being regular? Using scheme theoretic language, along with the fact that DVRs are regular local rings, this seems to be just a translation between geometric and algebraic statements.

Comment: I guess I have trouble with the zeros or poles part since it was never defined explicitly in the book.